# Angular UI-Router Not Recognizing State When Optional Parameters Provided

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using angular ui router to handle state transitions, and I have a state that I can't seem to properly resolve.

The state is:

```
.state('organization.program.editor', {
    url: "/editor/{contentId:[0-9]{1,8}}/{workflowStateId:[0,9]{1,8}}/{projectId:[0,9]{1,8}}",
    templateUrl: "editor-editor",
    controller: 'EditorController as vm',
    resolve: {
        editorModel: ['$stateParams', 'editorService', 'orgService',
            function ($stateParams, editorService, orgService) {
                debugger;
                //edited for brevity
                return null;

            }]
    },
    params: { contentId: {}, orgId: {}, programId: {},  
              workflowStateId: { value: '-1' }, projectId: { value: '-1' } }
        })
```

If I navigate to `/editor/2445`, the transition is accepted and it successfully navigates, and my optional parameters are their defaults, -1 and -1.

However, if I try `/editor/2445/1`, or `/editor/2445/1/1`, it does not recognize the state.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have any 'organization.program.editor' child state? for example 'organization.program.editor.otherState'..

Comment: @DaniCE, no, that's as low as it goes at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I solved this.  The problem is the params definition:

```
params: { contentId: {}, orgId: {}, programId: {},  
          workflowStateId: { value: '-1' }, projectId: { value: '-1' } }
```

Since I'm using numeric constraints in the url like so: `editor/{contentId:[0-9]{1,8}}/{workflowStateId:[0,9]{1,8}}/{projectId:[0,9]{1,8}}`, there are two violations in my param defaults.

First, `[0-9]{1,8}` will only match numeric values.  Second, it will only match positive numeric values.

So, the `'-1'` value provided will never match when applied.  It needs to be a number, and 0 or greater.

Hope it helps someone in the future.